# How to Achieve This Guitar Tone in Guitar Rig

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, scales, guitar-effects, overtones

I found Gorgeous cover song on youtube . i just really like to achieve this tone . in fact i like this tone better than the original one.

Thanks , Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

That is called "woman tone", really famous Les Paul tone..
You absolutly need the humbucker pickup on neck position (you can clearly see it in the video too), turn your tone knob down to somewhere between 0 and 2, volume knob at 10 and you are halfway there.

Slash usually used high volume and a lot of gain on his amplifiers to make the tubes scream. You could achieve it with the "HotPlex" amp in Guitar Rig (equivalent to some vintage Marshall).
I personally set my eq to Treble 7, Middle 3 and Bass 7 but it depends on your equipment.. For example, while I find that low mids help me achieve the tone, Slash used to boost his mids with a graphic eq!
No reverb, subtle delay, and not a lot of other effects is what made Slash tones so pure. And to my ear seems that the guy in the video does the same.

When I try to replicate a precise tone on Guitar Rig i find myself spending a lot of time playing with different cabinets and mics, it really can make the difference!

And yeah, as always, a lot of the tone is in the fingers of the player :) Good luck!